# Proving if $\chi(g) = d$ then, $X(g) = I$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This is already discussed a little bit: [If $X$ has character $\chi$ and degree $d$. Prove that $g \in N$ if and only if $\chi(g) = d$ . Hint: Show that $\chi(g)$ is a sum of roots of unity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671076/if-x-has-character-chi-and-degree-d-prove-that-g-in-n-if-and-only-if/1671092#1671092)

The question is as follows:
$X$ is a matrix representation of a group $G$, with character $\chi$ and degree $d$. Prove that $X(g) = I$ if and only if $\chi(g) = d$. The hint is: "Show that $\chi(g)$ is the sum of the roots of unity."

I'm specifically interested in proving that if $\chi(g) = d$, then $X(g) = I$. I'm honestly at a loss for where to even begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume $G$ must be finite. Do you know why $\chi(g)$ is the sum of roots of unity? (The hint is a good place to begin.)

Comment: I'm having trouble pinpointing why $\chi(g)$ is the sum of the roots of unity (And yes, G must be finite). I feel like it might have something to do with eigenvalues, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Do you know what the relationship between trace and eigenvalues is? Also, what can you say about the eigenvalues of the image of $G$?

Comment: Yep! Trace should be the sum of eigenvalues. I'm not so sure what the eigenvalues of the image of $G$ should be. I think it might have to do with the group being abelian and $X$ being a group homomorphism, but I can't seem to draw any meaningful conclusions.

Comment: This is not about $G$ being abelian. It only requires that $X$ is a homomorphism. We have to use that $G$ is finite. Let’s take the simplest case: if $G$ is the cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $a$, what can you say about $X(a)$?

Comment: We know that $X(a)$ generates the image. Then, for any $a^k$, $\phi(a^k) = \phi(a)^k$. In fact, since $G$ is finite, if we let $|G| = n$, then $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n = 1$ which allows us to conclude because $X(a)^n = 1$ means that the eigenvalues are the roots of unity. But to generalize to any finite group, I think we can just apply this logic to each cyclic subgroup of our finite $G$. Please let me know if there's something wrong with my logic!

Comment: That’s right, although I’d phrase that as applying this argument to each $a \in G$ rather than each cyclic subgroup. It may be useful to write this as an answer to your own question, to solicit feedback from others as well.

Comment: I'll write up a solution and post it in a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I will use a corollary and lemma from [Benjamin Steinberg's Representation Theory of Finite Groups - an Introductory Approach](http://users.metu.edu.tr/sozkap/513-2013/Steinberg.pdf)

Note that $g$ is an element of finite order and so $X(g)$ is a matrix of finite order in $GL_d(\mathbb{C})$. It is therefore diagonalizable (see Corollary 4.1.10), and its eigenvalues are $n$-th roots of unity. Thus $\chi_X(g)=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_d$ where $\lambda_i$ are $n$-th roots of unity. Now, $\chi_X(g)=d$ iff $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_d$ (see Lemma 6.3.1), and so $\chi_X(g)=d\lambda=d$ which implies $\lambda_i=1$ for all $i$, and so $X(g)$ is similar to $I$, meaning $X(g)=I$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

With some help, here's what I think the solution is. Please leave any comments/suggestions if you have any!

First, let's consider an arbitrary $a \in G$. Let $|a| = n$ ($G$ is finite, so every element must have finite order). If we consider some arbitrary element, $a \in G$ and $X: G \rightarrow GL_n$, since $|a| = n$, we also know that $X(a^n) = X(a)^n = 1$. Then $X(a)^n = I$. We know that we can diagonalize $X(a)$ with a basis of eigenvectors. Therefore, the eigenvalues are the roots of unity. Then, $\chi(g) = \sum_i^d \lambda_i$. Given that $\chi(g) = d$, $\lambda_i = 1$ for all $\lambda_i$ which implies that $X(g) = I$.